# How to consume and process AVRO data in GPU efficiently?

Tags: c++, c++11, cuda, avro

**Requirement :**

1. I have an application producing AVRO data (around 100 GB per hour).
2. I want to create another application that would read the generated AVRO data (hourly) and transform the data in GPU

**Example class generated by AVRO (not accurate but just to present my case) :**

```
struct XXX {
    std:string s1;
    std:string s2;
    int i1;
    float f1; 
}

struct YYY { 
    XXX x1;
    XXX x2;
    std:string s1;
    int i1;
}
```

**Problem :**

1. After de-serializing an AVRO record, it contains std::string in nested structure
2. GPU does not support std::string

*Question :*

Is there a way, to send the deserialized AVRO record to GPU for further processing as it is?

Please bear with me, if the question seems very naive, as I am new to both c++ and GPU programming.

Comment: struct YYY may have inner objects of struct XXX. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Removed the typedef

Comment: see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) for what `typedef` actually does. Nowadays `typedef` is largely obsolete in c++ (`using` for aliases instead)

Comment: Thanks but I just replicated the class generated by AVRO.

Comment: I dont know your original code, maybe it has `typedef`s in that place, but it seemed you want to have members instead...the code wasnt wrong, just not clear what the `typedef` were good for

Comment: Why don't you compact all strings in a single char array then prepare their starting indices(not pointers) on a second array or just inside where they come from? If you think some of them are same and need to be optimized, then maybe you filter them using a map first, then get compacted output of map into CUDA so that multiple strings with same data won't harrass cache.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but cudf has a gpu loader for avro files and supports strings https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment please visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of using GPU? Is it performance? Because understanding how the machine interprets the code is significantly more efficient than using GPU. If you are using AVRO code gen (which you state you are above) you are already not going to get real performance improvements. I wrote some custom Avro serializers and got 100x improvements on serialization over generated code. If you want to transform deserialization to GPU I would recommend first writing out a deserializer your self, by hand, for your particular Avro schema, and then try to convert that to GPU.

Comment: As you pointed out correctly, the purpose is to improve performance. I tried spark (with 10 executors) but could not reach the desired performance. I will try out the custom deserializer idea.

Comment: Can you please guide me towards how to write custom Avro Serializers?

Comment: Take a look at the avro specifications here: https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html

Comment: Also take a look at the C source code here:
https://github.com/apache/avro/tree/master/lang/c

Comment: Finnally, you should use the generated code for comparison. Serilize your data using the generated code (which out any speed improvements) and compare the out put to any custom results you generate.